# Why does perl regex .* not recognize \n in a null delimited record. $/="\0'

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I'm trying to parse some `\x00` null-delimited data.  I thought that in a `-pe/-ne` loop, `$_` would be equivalent to `.*` in the pattern matching side of a substitution regex... However as my example shows, they are not the same...

```
                                                  #      ↓↓‾‾ works, but is not a regex
printf 'aaa\n\0bbb\n\0' | perl -ne 'BEGIN{ $/="\0"; }; s/$_/\"$.$&\"/ and print;' |xxd
printf 'aaa\n\0bbb\n\0' | perl -ne 'BEGIN{ $/="\0"; }; s/.*/\"$.$&\"/ and print;' |xxd
                                                  #      ↑↑__ gives un-expected output

# output                                          #      ↓       ↓ 
0000000: 2231 6161 610a 0022 2232 6262 620a 0022  "1aaa..""2bbb.."
0000000: 2231 6161 6122 0a00 2232 6262 6222 0a00  "1aaa".."2bbb"..
                                                  #    ↑       ↑
```

What is needed to get an `s/ / /` type of substitution to recognize the full `$_` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.` does not match `\n` unless the `/s` modifier is used.

```
printf 'aaa\n\0bbb\n\0' | perl -ne 'BEGIN{ $/="\0"; }; s/.*/\"$.$&\"/s and print;' |xxd
```

Alternately, a character class could be used instead of `.`.

```
printf 'aaa\n\0bbb\n\0' | perl -ne 'BEGIN{ $/="\0"; }; s/[\s\S]*/\"$.$&\"/ and print;' |xxd
```

Here, `[\s\S]` matches any space or non-space character (in other words, any character).

Comment: Thanks, I figured it had to be simple.. (once you know).  That's interesting combo of character classes :)

Comment: `(?s:.)` matches any char too.